# Coloring of the edge of the 1*3 grid

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, coloring

I am trying to find the number of distinct coloring in the following problem:

Consider a 1*3 grid (shown as below) using 10 sticks and 8 balls. Color sticks with $m$ colors. How many ways are there to color the sticks with $m$ colors? 
[image: The balls are indistinguishable, but the edges are distinct and numbered.]

I try to use Burnside's lemma to count the distinct coloring, but I cannot find all the symmetric groups. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This looks to have only four automorphisms which are easily factored into cycles.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I think the symmetries are identity, 180 rotations, reflection with respect to the horizontal axis of symmetry and vertical axis of symmetry. Am I right?@MarkoRiedel

Comment: That would be correct. These can be factored from the table notation or more effectively, by inspection.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel Thank you for your response. I have found all the symmetries of this figure and have solved my problem.